# Why would fastlane scan tests keep rebuilding and running in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

I have a pipeline job running on Jenkins that runs iOS unit tests.

I'm seeing some really strange behaviour when our tests fail, fastlane shows the failure in it's summary, but then begins to rebuild the code and re-test.

This happens continually, and I can not figure out if it's a fastlane/scan setting I am missing, or something with running this in a Jenkins Pipeline.

`bundle exec fastlane test` runs locally just fine, and only executes once per device defined in my scan file.

My console output looks like so:

```
[11:26:36]: fastlane finished with errors
[!] Test execution failed. Exit status: 65
#######################################################################
# fastlane 2.19.3 is available. You are on 2.17.0.
# It is recommended to use the latest version.
# Please update using `bundle update fastlane`.
#######################################################################
2.19.3 sigh Hotfix
* fix sigh undefined variable regression (#8457)
2.19.2 Snapshot improvements and more
* Add tests for ReportsGenerator available_devices
* Fix HTML report generation for snapshot
* Prioritize options passed to supply
* Collect logs for iOS 10+ devices
* Add row for Fabric.app-installed fastlane to env command
* Sigh reports better errors for team members
* Expand the notes_path parameter
* Update xcov intialization
2.19.1 Hot fix for provisioning profile creation/deletion
- Re-implement csrf token retrieval for provisioning profiles (#8410)
- don't attempt to create apps on the dev center and itc if mac app (#8404)
To see all new releases, open https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases
Please update using `bundle update fastlane`
/Users/hudson/build/workspace/MNELastWord-PR-Pipeline@tmp/durable-ba2bbebe/script.sh: line 2: shell_session_update: command not found
Sending interrupt signal to process
▸ Cleaning Pods/CocoaLumberjack-iOS [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Cleaning Pods/Bento-iOS-Lib-iOS-BentoResources [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Cleaning Pods/AFNetworking-iOS [Debug]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Cleaning Pods/JSONModel-iOS [Debug]
```

You can see after fastlane completes, it just goes on it's merry way and starts to rebuild and re-test instead of exiting the job.

Based on this output, I *think* it's something in Fastlane causing this to re-execute, because there's no output from Jenkins that indicates the stage is getting called again.

That said, I see nothing in fastlane issues on Github about this, other than Snapshot having a retry option (which I am not using snapshot)

for completeness, here's my [Scanfile](https://gist.github.com/kaosdg/b920c658eec9a3def83bd7180ee124ab), [Jenkinsfile](https://gist.github.com/kaosdg/a1e94c2000da1febdcf4f9618e91c54a), and [Fastfile](https://gist.github.com/kaosdg/46c28f5d839a90c66504d37ada804582)

and screens from relevant jenkins config: [image: Jenkins Screenshot]

Can someone help out here?  I've tried the latest fastlane, older fastlanes, and still see the behaviour.

My DevOps and SAs are getting pretty upset with us because our jobs never end, and are hanging our jenkins nodes :) (aborting/terminating them is really problematic)

Comment: My gut says that something in Jenkins is configured to re-run this. For our setup, we have a 'Execute Shell' build step that simply calls `bundle exec fastlane test` and it works fine. Your Scanfile and Fastfile seem fine. Can you share the Configure screen for the Jenkins job?

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson There's nothing really in there except the parameter definitions and telling pipeline to pull the Jenkinsfile from SCM, but here's the relevant settings anyway (adding to original post)

Comment: Are you calling bundle exec fastlane test in a shell script? It is not in a loop? Or in a loop that re-runs if there is an 'error' in scan? If there are any failed tests, scan will return a non-zero error code and Jenkins may consider that a failure

Comment: Your use of `@NonCPS` is questionable (and in (almost?) all cases unnecessary) — you shouldn't normally be able to use Pipeline steps inside such methods, so there may be unexpected side-effects there. Try removing the annotation from your methods. Also, you're calling `set +e` on the `sh` step and overriding the Jenkins default, which exits a shell script immediately when an error occurs.. but as you're only running one command at a time, that should be fine.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr, without the `@NonCPS` annotation jenkins will fail with non-serializable exceptions.  (due to my use of hashes to iterate - i could refactor that but it wasn't the cause of my main issue).

And i've tried all manner of `sh` settings, they never made a difference in how that one fastlane command behaved.  (manually loading the environment using `withEnv`, hard-paths to bundler, etc.)

Comment: @KaosDG That's why I said in _almost_ all cases it should be unnecessary :) But for the other methods, especially the `bash` one, it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

So ultimately I think I've gotten to the bottom of the issue here.

If I wrap my Test stage in a try/catch block, then I get appropriate behaviour from the job.

```
stage 'Tests'
            try {
                    env.FASTLANE_EXPLICIT_OPEN_SIMULATOR = 1
                    bash 'bundle exec fastlane test'
                } catch (e) {
                    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                    throw e
                }
```

This doesn't really make sense since my entire section is wrapped in a try/catch - so if someone has insight as to WHY this works, i'm all ears.
But at least I am able to work around the issue right now.

Comment: I know that when I run `scan` in a Fastfile, it throws a Ruby Exception.  In my plugin that suppresses passing tests for a another scan of the failed tests, I catch and retry if it failed less than 3 times. See https://github.com/lyndsey-ferguson/fastlane_plugins/blob/master/fastlane-plugin-setup_fragile_tests_for_rescan/fastlane/Fastfile#L14

Answer (score 1):

Looks like test case is failing but Jenkins job is not stopping.
Could be two possibilities here:

1. Try exiting the job once the test case fails, so it won't continue after, hence added explicit exit 1 if test case execution fails 
   Example

   ```
   stage('Run Tests') {

   // Shell build step
   sh """ 
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "Executing Fastlane test lane..."
   $HOME/.fastlane/bin/fastlane tests || exit 1;
   """     
   }
   ```
2. Check if test case changing if source code file and doing the commit back to the SCM, and on commit/push Jenkins would be polling hence resulting in a loop.

To solve this use polling ignore on commit/user/message basis. Adding screenshot for reference

[image]